Lightning:QuickAction Modal not rendering correctly when clicked for the first time
I have a lightning action which includes a lightning aura component. In my lightning component i have applied some custom styling in order to improve the modal view.
customAuraComponent.cmp:
<aura:component implements="lightning:availaibleForFlowScreens,force:hasRecordId,lightning:actionOverride,lightning:isUrlAddressable,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,flexipage:availaibleForAllPageTypes">
<aura:html tag="style">
    .slds-modal{
    /*some custom css*/
    }
    .slds-modal__content{
    /*some custom css*/
    }
    @media(min-width:40em){
          .slds-modal__container{
          /*some custom css*/
          }
    }
</aura:html>
    <div style="border-left:outset;">
       <div class="slds-modal__header">
          <h1>Header</h1>
       </div>
       <div class="slds-modal__content">
          <!--body html-->
       </div>
       <div class="slds-modal__footer">
          <!--footer html-->
       </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>

When i click the action for the first time it shows me a very malformed modal. The modal is positioned more towards the top of the page. It shows a very basic modal with none of my custom styling applied to it.
But, once i do a hard refresh or Ctrl + Shift + R on the record detail page, where my lightning action is placed, and then click on the action, the modal renders correctly with my custom styling applied to it.
Does anybody know why this is happening and how can i fix this?
